# show/hide DIV when passed the other div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want a `hidden` `div` show if he passed the another DIV. for example show in `html` below if `div.passedMe` bottom! meet the top of the window, the `div.showHide` will show and when `scroll up` and the `div.passedMe` top! meet the top of the window the `div.showHide` will hide.

**Html**

```
<div class="passedMe">If you passed this div another div will show/hide</div>

<div class="showHide"> this div will show/hide</div>
```

so far this is what I have but this only work when passed a  certain `PIXEL` on A page

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        $('.showHide').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.showHide').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/1426/)

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: I think you are trying to do some floating animation. But I could not understand how you need to animate 2 div 's

Comment: write a jsfiddle with the code you have tried (mousein, mouseout, show, hide, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="passedMe">If you passed this div another div will show/hide</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="showHide" style="display:none;"> this div will show/hide</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function(){
                    var vis = ($(document).scrollTop() > ($('.passedMe').offset().top+$('.passedMe').height()));
                            $('.showHide').css('display', vis?'':'none')
                                });
        });
</script>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

And if you wish to fadein/fadeout then instead of:

```
$('.showHide').css('display', vis?'':'none');
```

use

```
if (vis) $('.showHide').fadeIn(); else $('.showHide').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to get the divs offset position from the top relevant to the window height and compare when you scrolled passed it and show the hidden div. Check the Demo i prepared.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/b2sjk9pL/

```
var p = $( ".passedMe" );
var offset = p.offset();
offset = offset.top;

$(window).scroll(function () {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop()   >  offset ) {
 $('.showHide').fadeIn();
    }
  else { $('.showHide').fadeOut(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this Jquery plugin.

https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/

```
if ($('.element').visible(true)) {
    // Element is visible - do something
} else {
    // Element is NOT visible - do something else
}
```

And then you can try to detect if user scroll.

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// When the window is scrolled.  
}
```

So something like this. (untested)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.visible.js"></script>
</hed>

window.onscroll = function (e) {  
 if ($('.passedMe').visible(true)) {
        $('.showHide').fadeIn();
    } else {
        // Element is NOT visible - do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download animate.css from this link http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ and call it in your html

Then add class 'animated' to div and you can apply a animation to your div by using  'data-animation' i.e data-animation="flipInY", Here 'flipInY' is how your div should be appear when user scrolls down. You can change the data-animation as you required.
You can also apply delay for the div by using 'data-animation' i.e data-animation-delay="400"

```
<div class="passedMe animated" data-animation="flipInY" data-animation-delay="400">If you passed this div another div will show/hide</div>

<div class="showHide animated" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="400"> this div will show/hide</div>
```

Add include the following code in your css

```
.animated {
visibility: hidden;
}

.visible{
visibility: visible;
}
```

Don't forget to include animate.css in your html file

Then download jQuery.appear from http://plugins.jquery.com/appear/ and call it in your html

Later include following the script at the end of body

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.animated').appear(function() {
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    var animation = elem.data('animation');
    if ( !elem.hasClass('visible') ) {
      var animationDelay = elem.data('animation-delay');

      if ( animationDelay ) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          elem.addClass( animation + " visible" );
        }, animationDelay);

      } else {
        elem.addClass( animation + " visible" );

      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You don't need all these plugins. It will just weigh your site down and make it very slow if you use a plugin every time you need to do a simple bit of jQuery.