# jQuery scroll event behavior

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, transition

I have a general question on scroll events.

Lets assume that I have a `div` called `.notification`. When the user scrolls past 500, I want to add a class `.ns--show`. If they are less than 500, I want to add the class `.ns--hide`, but only if the user has already scrolled past 500.

Here is the jQuery code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (st >= 500) {
   $('.notification').addClass('ns--show');
  } else {
   $('.notification').removeClass('ns--show').addClass('ns--hide');
  }
});
```

The issue I am having is that the when the browser loads, the scrollTop is 0. Therefore it adds the class `.ns--hide` immediately on load and the dom looks like:

```
<div class="notification ns--hide"></div>
```

Is there a way to write this so that it works like "Do not add `ns--hide` unless the user has scrolled past 500, and then scrolls back up less than 500"

Note: I can't simply remove the same class `ns--show` as I am using css transitions/transforms that change the way the div looks on the hide class.

Edit:

I came up with a solution based on post below:

```
if (st >= 500) {
 if ($('.notification').hasClass('ns--hide')) {
  $('.notification').removeClass('ns--hide').addClass('ns--show');
 } else {
  $('.notification').addClass('ns--show');
 }
 } else {
  if ($('.notification').hasClass('ns--show')) {
   $('.notification').removeClass('ns--show').addClass('ns--hide');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok have a look at this question, its similar to yours and see if it helps -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660289/show-hide-div-when-passed-the-other-div/25661103#25661103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *flag* that indicates the **ns-show** class is added.

For example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (st >= 500) {
   $('.notification').removeClass('ns--hide');.addClass('ns--show class-added');
  } else {
   if($('.notification').hasClass('class-added'))
     $('.notification').removeClass('ns--show class-added').addClass('ns--hide');
  }
});
```

The *class-added* is a flag that helps you to know when the scroll passes 500px.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! This behavior only works on first pass through up/down. The second time you go through the div is "notification ns--flip class-added ns--hide" and then when you scroll back down again it becomes "notification ns--flip class-added ns--hide ns--show"

Comment: Hmmm, if I understand correctly, you can solve it removing the class-added with ns--show, better say, if the else condition is true. Right?

Comment: I need it to add ns--show when its past 500, and remove ns--show and add ns--hide when its less than 500, however if the user is starting at 0, ns--hide is firing, when I need it to only fire after the user has been past 500 and going back up to less than 500.

Comment: I'm starting to think what I need to use is on transitionend,remove the class. That way when the transition has ended on ns--hide, I can remove that. This logic though does not solve that when the browser loads, scrollTop = 0.

Comment: It's no correct, if the scrollTop is 0, the ns--hide is not firing because _.notification_ has not class _class-added_. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried out your code. It works on the first scroll down and up. The second time it does what my first comment says.

Comment: I've updated my answer, as I said, I think it works if you remove the _class-added_ class in the else condition.

Comment: Yes thats pretty much it, however it needs to remove ns--hide once the transition is done. So I believe transitionend event is my answer. Also, I could instead do hasClass('no--show') instead of adding another class and it works the same way yours is suggesting which is nice. Thoughts for the transitionend idea, or perhaps a SetTimeout?

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct. I've updated my answer with how I solved it based on your logic. It works now as I need.